# ImageView variable returning null even after defined; Android

Tags: android

In my program I am trying to display an image from a file using an ImageView. I have declared the ImageView to be related to an ImageView XML file and have set the value to be an image from a file using BitmapFactory. After all this, I still am receiving a NullPointerException because the ImageView variable is apparently still null. If you have any ideas or advice, please let me know, thanks!

Here's the code I am talking about:

```
public void imageViewMethod(String file){
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.example.myclass");

    try {

    File fileName = new File(root, file);
    if(fileName.exists()){
    String dirFileName = fileName.toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dirFileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirFileName));
    super.setContentView(iv);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hit Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "uncaught exception", e);
    }
}
```

And the corresponding XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 

android:layout_margin="5dp">
</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks you have not set the ContentView in oncreate you have to set ContentView before getting ImageView

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.correspondingXML);
```

Comment: The reason I didn't set the ContentView in the onCreate is because originally the display is a listview containing the file names. Once a file name is selected it opens this method in an attempt to display the image. Perhaps I should use intents and start a new activity? Any more ideas?

Comment: ok so your current activity has list not the xml as in question as contentview ?

Comment: Yes, the current activity has a list adapter to display the file names. Then in the onItemClick method I retrieve the file name that was pressed and call 'imageViewMethod(f2);' - with f2 being the file name.

Comment: then yes not need to create the new activity and setcontent view in that as image.xml and then will get Imageview and have to pass data through intent like file name here ........

Comment: and then no need to call super.setContentView(iv); after setting image in Imageview...

Comment: one thing I need to confirm ..you are looking image with list or only image on screen ?

Comment: I only want the image to be displayed on the screen once the file name is clicked.

Comment: yup then create a new activity  pass data through intent like file name here and  setcontent view in that as image.xml and then will get Imageview and then no need to call super.setContentView(iv); after setting image in Imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly set the `contentView()`? It seems you have used `super.setContentView(iv);` at the wrong place. `setContentView(R.layout.imageviewLayout.xml)` is used in the `onCreate()` of the activity class.

Check if you have the following code in the activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imageviewLayout.xml);
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get imageview before setting contentview.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the layout while your Activity is running, try using a LayoutInflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
setContentView(view);
```

Now `findViewById(R.id.image)` will work.