# How to display image in ImageView from Bitmap... ImageView variable returns null

Tags: android, imageview, bitmapfactory

I have a problem with displaying the image from bitmap.
I'm getting the base64 encoded string from JsonObject and decoded to get byte array and bitmap after. 
I was unlucky with this so I'm trying now with the same image from drawable.

Now the problem is i'm getting the null pointer exceptions when setting image bitmap in imageView
and have no idea why...

Have read this : [ImageView variable returning null even after defined; Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276649/imageview-variable-returning-null-even-after-defined-android)

The code for whole class is: `package com.statsports.subjectiveandroid;

```
public class PlayersListActivity extends Activity {

    // URL to make request
    private static String URL = "http://000.000.00.0/index.php";
    private static int userID;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> playersList;
    ListView playerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        userID = extras.getInt("id");
        initLayout();
    }

    private void initLayout() {

        playerView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        playersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        playerView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(PlayersListActivity.this,
                playersList, R.layout.activity_players_list, null, null));

        //playerView.setDividerHeight(0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (!ConnectivityStatus.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayersListActivity.this, R.string.network_failed,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            playerView.setAdapter(null);
            new PlayersLoadTask().execute();
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    class PlayersLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayersListActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Reading data");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            playersList.clear();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {

                ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", "getPlayers"));
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clubid", Integer
                        .toString(userID)));

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(PlayersListActivity.URL);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters,
                        ("ISO-8859-1")));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                // if this is null the web service returned an empty page
                if (httpEntity == null) // response is empty so exit out
                    return null;

                String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                // again some simple validation around the returned string
                if (jsonString != null && jsonString.length() != 0) // checking
                                                                    // string
                                                                    // returned
                                                                    // from
                                                                    // service
                                                                    // to grab
                                                                    // id
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                        int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        String base64 = jsonObject.getString("image");
                        map.put("id", id);
                        map.put("name", name);
                        if (name == null || name.trim().length() == 0) {
                            name = "Player unknown";
                        } else {
                            map.put("image", (R.drawable.baboon));
                        }

                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.walcott);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                        Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

                        image.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
                        //ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        //byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(
                        //      base64.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_PADDING);
                        /*
                         * InputStream is = new
                         * ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString); Bitmap bitmap =
                         * BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                         * bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                         * stream);
                         * 
                         * if(bitmap != null){ //Drawable drawableImg = new
                         * BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap); ImageView
                         * imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                         * imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); map.put("image",
                         * bitmap); }
                         */

                        //String images = new String(decodedString);
                        //Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                        //      decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        //decodedByte.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                        //      stream);
                        //Log.d("DECODEDBYTE IS: ", decodedByte.toString());

                        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_players_list, null);
                        //setContentView(view);
                        //ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                        //imgView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

                        playersList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR SOMEWHERE!!!! ", e.toString());
            }
            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (playersList.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(PlayersListActivity.this,
                        "No players in a list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                playerView.setAdapter(new PlayerListAdapter(
                        PlayersListActivity.this, playersList,
                        R.layout.activity_players_list, new String[] { "id",
                                "image", "name" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.player_list_id, R.id.image, R.id.name, }));
            }

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you call `image.setImageBitmap(bmp1);` in doInBackground. you can't do that.

Comment: plus, chances are `findViewById(R.id.image);` refers to a view in the list row layout. in which case, it is not inflated when you call this, because there is no row in the listview.

Comment: `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
setContentView(view);` did not helped tho.